# unrecognized output wallet when using Electrum to send bitcoin

Tags: transactions, network

help me understand this transaction - https://www.blockchain.com/ro/btc/tx/1318a3e54cff78fdd8f6b54e6fe5115072586091788c9bfa08ca82d83e4bc276 .

Never sent bitcoin from hardware / hot wallet before so I am new to this

So I tried a demo send from one wallet ******c276** to my crypto.com wallet ****xmhue**

- so I understand that my wallet was converted to a new wallet ******qhev** with the remaining amount

what I don't understand:

- 0.001 of my bitcoin got sent to the correct crypto.com wallet, but 0.001 of my bitcoin got sent to a unrecognized wallet - *****myAn** - I don't understand what this is
- I don't know how Electrum chose that wallet for sending the payment , is the choosing of the wallet automatic from Electrum ?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how Electrum chose that wallet for sending the payment , is the choosing of the wallet automatic from Electrum ?

Maybe its a change address. You can read about change addresses in the below links:

[What does change address mean inside Electrum wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50050/what-does-change-address-mean-inside-electrum-wallet)

[What all the addresses are in my Electrum wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96004/what-all-the-addresses-are-in-my-electrum-wallet)

[image: tx-screenshot]

I am not sure why change address is starting with "3" which can be a p2sh-segwit address because input address `bc1qxesjp5g4d23kpt9xghwxlu4mfhu9xxrehp0ytnm023ely43kdh9spsy4k7` is most likely an address from 2 of 3 multisig wallet with p2wsh addresses.

[image: multisig]

Comment: yeah, but I cannot find it in my ADDRESSES tab :(

Comment: Then its not an address from your wallet and you added it in the outputs while creating transaction. Or if this is a wallet used by 3 people and 2 of them signed the transaction, then maybe other person added it in outputs so `bc1qxesjp5g4d23kpt9xghwxlu4mfhu9xxrehp0ytnm023ely43kdh9spsy4k7` is input, `bc1qlctcpg486aw0t9kps659evc26pszg2h22xmhue` is crypto.com address, `bc1qjg9rgaeuvx85cw7ssvtnyutrnq230k5ycl54m84mfj5096p0c8qq00qhev` is change address and `3Kxa9XGD4VJqm1y7vd31YNNCVBCEUgmyAn` UNKNOWN ADDRESS added by you or other cosigner.

Comment: seems it might have been added from my Electrum Software

Comment: https://api.trustedcoin.com/#/electrum-help